# Flutter web ListView.builder showing nothing

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Could you help me solve this problem of showing nothing in listview.builder after a flutter web app released as shown in the next picture, although working well in the android release.
I tried to shorten city list but the problem still  present
[Code link](https://www.github.com/shazlycode/weather_app_flutter/tree/master/lib%2Fscreens%2Fsearch_screen.dart)
[Code link](https://codeshare.io/5QxMKx)

Comment: Can you include your `ListView.builder()` here in code and the error image as well?

Comment: I tried to add the code, but this message appeared even after shorten it. 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'

Comment: i've created this Dartpad https://dartpad.dev/62deeb2566ace6a783381c081a383654 to be able to test your code. And it's working fine

**Note** : You were returning null in you listview.builder so i changed it to SizedBox().

Comment: Thanx for your quick reply, the problem only in the release not in the debug mode. I already published this app in Google play and this problem still exists. You can check it out https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shazlycode.weather

Comment: @AhmedElshazly So this problem only happens for you when build a web release?

Comment: @Bach recently I found this problem happens in both android and web release and this is the links of web app and android. Web: https://shop-app-clone2.web.app/#/   Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shazlycode.weather

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that you either used the `ListView.builder()` method incorrectly or that you are inserting a list child that has `Expanded()` which means that since `ListView` can scroll, have an expanded widget or child which takes up as much space will basically not show since Flutter doesn't know how much space it should take.

If you could share your code perhaps, then it would be much easier to figure out what the issue exactly is.

EDIT

I just checked your dartpad and I suggest perhaps giving the following code a try:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SearchScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  dynamic cityWeatherData;
  bool isLoading = false;
  String cityName = '';
  List cities = [
    City(city: "Cairo", lat: 30.05, long: 31.25),
    City(city: "Alexandria", lat: 31.2, long: 29.95),
    City(city: "Giza", lat: 30.01, long: 31.19),
    City(city: "Ismailia", lat: 30.5903, long: 32.26),
    City(city: "Port Said", lat: 31.26, long: 32.29),
    City(city: "Luxor", lat: 25.7, long: 32.65),
    City(city: "Suhaj", lat: 26.5504, long: 31.7),
    City(city: "Al Mansurah", lat: 31.0504, long: 31.38),
    City(city: "Suez", lat: 30.005, long: 32.5499),
    City(city: "Damanhur", lat: 31.0504, long: 30.47),
    City(city: "Al Minya", lat: 28.09, long: 30.75),
    City(city: "Bani Suwayf", lat: 29.0804, long: 31.09),
    City(city: "Asyut", lat: 27.19, long: 31.1799),
    City(city: "Tanta", lat: 30.7904, long: 31),
    City(city: "Al Fayyum", lat: 29.31, long: 30.84),
    City(city: "Aswan", lat: 24.0875, long: 32.8989),
    City(city: "Kawm Umbu", lat: 24.47, long: 32.95),
    City(city: "Qina", lat: 26.1505, long: 32.72),
    City(city: "Damietta", lat: 31.4204, long: 31.82),
    City(city: "Az Zaqaziq", lat: 30.5833, long: 31.5167),
    City(city: "Mallawi", lat: 27.7304, long: 30.84),
    City(city: "Rosetta", lat: 31.4604, long: 30.39),
    City(city: "Shibin al Kawm", lat: 30.592, long: 30.9),
    City(city: "Al `Arish", lat: 31.1249, long: 33.8006),
    City(city: "Banha", lat: 30.4667, long: 31.1833),
    City(city: "Al Ghardaqah", lat: 27.23, long: 33.83),
    City(city: "Samalut", lat: 28.3004, long: 30.71),
    City(city: "Kafr ash Shaykh", lat: 31.109, long: 30.936),
    City(city: "Jirja", lat: 26.3304, long: 31.88),
    City(city: "Marsa Matruh", lat: 31.3504, long: 27.23),
    City(city: "Al Kharijah", lat: 25.44, long: 30.55),
    City(city: "At Tur", lat: 28.2394, long: 33.6148),
    City(city: "Isna", lat: 25.2904, long: 32.5499),
    City(city: "Bani Mazar", lat: 28.4904, long: 30.81),
    City(city: "Safaja", lat: 26.7337, long: 33.9333),
    City(city: "Siwah", lat: 29.2, long: 25.5167),
    City(city: "Ad Dab`ah", lat: 31.0338, long: 28.4333),
    City(city: "Al `Alamayn", lat: 30.8171, long: 28.95),
    City(city: "As Sallum", lat: 31.567, long: 25.15),
    City(city: "Qasr al Farafirah", lat: 27.0671, long: 27.9666),
    City(city: "Al Qasr", lat: 25.7004, long: 28.8833),
    City(city: "Barnis", lat: 23.946, long: 35.4842),
    City(city: "Jeddah", lat: 21.5169, long: 39.2192),
    City(city: "Ad Dammam", lat: 26.4282, long: 50.0997),
    City(city: "Mecca", lat: 21.43, long: 39.82),
    City(city: "Medina", lat: 24.5, long: 39.58),
    City(city: "At Ta'if", lat: 21.2622, long: 40.3823),
    City(city: "Al Hufuf", lat: 25.3487, long: 49.5856),
    City(city: "Al Hillah", lat: 23.4895, long: 46.7564),
    City(city: "Tabuk", lat: 28.3838, long: 36.555),
    City(city: "Buraydah", lat: 26.3664, long: 43.9628),
    City(city: "Ha'il", lat: 27.5236, long: 41.7001),
    City(city: "Najran", lat: 17.5065, long: 44.1316),
    City(city: "Al Qatif", lat: 26.5196, long: 50.0115),
    City(city: "Al Mubarraz", lat: 25.4291, long: 49.5659),
    City(city: "Al Kharj", lat: 24.1556, long: 47.312),
    City(city: "Yanbu`", lat: 24.0943, long: 38.0493),
    City(city: "Hafar al Batin", lat: 28.4337, long: 45.9601),
    City(city: "Al Jubayl", lat: 27.0046, long: 49.646),
    City(city: "`Ar`ar", lat: 30.99, long: 41.0207),
    City(city: "Abha", lat: 18.2301, long: 42.5001),
    City(city: "Sakaka", lat: 30, long: 40.1333),
    City(city: "Jazan", lat: 16.9066, long: 42.5566),
    City(city: "Al Bahah", lat: 20.0129, long: 41.4677),
    City(city: "Dhahran", lat: 26.2914, long: 50.1583),
    City(city: "Qal`at Bishah", lat: 20.0087, long: 42.5987),
    City(city: "Rafha", lat: 29.6202, long: 43.4948),
    City(city: "Al Wajh", lat: 26.2324, long: 36.4636),
    City(city: "As Sulayyil", lat: 20.4623, long: 45.5722),
    City(city: "Dawmat al Jandal", lat: 29.8153, long: 39.8664),
    City(city: "Al Qurayyat", lat: 31.3333, long: 37.3333),
    City(city: "Al Quway`iyah", lat: 24.0737, long: 45.2806),
    City(city: "Al Qunfudhah", lat: 19.1264, long: 41.0789),
  ];
  List result = [];
  double cityLong = 0;
  double cityLat = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/city1.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                  Colors.black.withOpacity(.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
            ),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Enter City...",
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    cityName = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  isLoading = true;
                  if (cityWeatherData == null) {
                    isLoading = true;
                  } else {
                    isLoading = false;
                    Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = {
                      'cityWeatherData': cityWeatherData,
                      'cityName': cityName
                    };
                    Navigator.pop(context, data);
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Get Weather',
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: cities.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return cityName.isEmpty
                        ? Container()
                        : cities[index]
                                .city
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(cityName.toLowerCase())
                            ? ListTile(
                                title: Text(cities[index].city),
                                onTap: () async {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      _controller.text = cities[index].city;
                                      cityName = _controller.text;

                                      print(cityName);

                                      cityLong = cities[index].long;
                                      cityLat = cities[index].lat;
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                              )
                            : Container();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class City {
  final String city;
  final double long;

  final double lat;
  City({this.city = '', this.lat = 0, this.long = 0});
}
```

Comment: He shared his code in the question. Or @Steve Noose create the dartpad here: https://dartpad.dev/62deeb2566ace6a783381c081a383654